# bind before connect

Tags: 14.04, networking, ipv4

i'm new to ubuntu and networking

Is there a method in Linux to check how many ephemeral ports are left available? I've problem with "Address already in use" errors as a result of running out of ephemeral ports

and how can i do this 
1- Set tcp_tw_reuse sysctl to enable reusing of TIME_WAIT sockets.

Comment: Run `netstat -an`

Comment: i ran it , i got alot of lines but couldn't see all of them

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. (https://serverfault.com/questions/261663/on-linux-how-can-i-tell-how-many-ephemeral-ports-are-left-available).

*The ephermal port range is specified in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. You can probably extend it to run from 16k to 64k.*

*You can see the number of open connections using `netstat -an`. Sockets may be stuck in TIME_WAIT state if you are opening and closing a lot of connections. In some places this is unavoidable, but you may need to consider if you need a pool of connection if this is the case.*

*If TIME_WAIT is the problem, you can set `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` / `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle` to speed up connection turnover.*

The latter refers to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` which thus can be set to 1 or 0. E.g.,

```
echo 1 | /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

Doing that will set the flag until next reboot. If you want the setting also after reboot, you need to add corresponding lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. E.g.,

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Anywhere in the file will do, and presumably you'll add some comment(s) about it as well.

Also, if your netstat output is excessive, consider piping it through a pager, e.g.

```
netstat -an | less
```

Comment: thanks, now i tested the port with  netstat -ntape
and got
Code:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6703            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       22776       2621/java
then used this command with PID of PORT = 2621
Code:
 lsof -P -w -n -p 2621 -a -i
and got
Code:
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    2621 user   76u  IPv4  18906      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:50036->127.0.0.1:2181 (ESTABLISHED)
java    2621 user   83u  IPv4  22773      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:56733->127.0.0.1:3773 (ESTABLISHED)
java    2621 user   86u  IPv4  22776      0t0  TCP *:6703 (LISTEN)

Comment: is there something wrong  ?

Comment: You tell me. Something waits for connections on port 6703, and there are some TCP connections made. Maybe don't tell me, rather.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you mean ?